# CUDA installation on MAC OS X without GPU (for cuda emulator)

Tags: macos, cuda, nvidia

I'm installing CUDA on MAC OS X by following the link below:

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/index.html

It says that I must have CUDA-enabled GPU before installing.I don't have a GPU in my MacBook Pro, and I want to run CUDA programs on Emulator. How can I do that? How to install CUDA on non-GPU laptop?

Comment: The cuda 5 installer should have command line switches (run with --help to see options) that allow you to extract separate installers for the driver,toolkit,and samples.  See if you can extract the toolkit installer and then run it separately (only).

Comment: By the way there is no emulator in cuda 5 so I'm not sure which emulator you plan to use or if any are compatible with cuda 5.

Answer (score 4):

You can try out [gpuocelot](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/).
It's a compilation framework that allows to use cuda code on non-cuda hardware as x86 cpus. I nerver used it on my own, but know some people who uses it and it works for them.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It probably doesn't work on CUDA 5. I'm not sure

Comment: Sorry, but can't give you further help to gpuocelt, because I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: More recent source code can be found via GitHub [gtcasl/gpuocelot](https://github.com/gtcasl/gpuocelot).